# 500 Error when running Cheesy Website locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby and I am currently reading Cucumber and Cheese for automated testing. Part of the exercise is to install the Puppies website locally.

I cloned the site here https://github.com/cheezy/puppies to my macbook pro which uses ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]

My rails version= Rails 3.2.11 - This is stated in the gem file but unsure if this needs to be updated to the latest version>?

I followed the steps as instructed but when I run the Rails S Webbrick command, enter localhost:300 I get the following:

***"We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."***

I checked the logs and it advises that it has started in development ok but then displays this:

```
Started GET "/agency/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-23 11:27:34 +0100
Processing by AgencyController#index as HTML
Rendered agency/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms"
```

I can't find any other information to help me look into. Any help on this and I would very thankful.

Cheers

Comment: You have to install `ruby 1.9.x` (i,e 1,9.3) using rvm. bundle install & rails s.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added ruby 1.9.3. but needed to re add rails. When I did I got this:ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

Comment: My fault - I had to reinstall Bundler. Once I installed and the ran bundle install it all worked. Thank you so much for sorting